# How to close google chrome using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Here I'm trying to close a single tab using javascript, but it doesn't work in chrome ver 38 (works fine in ver 28). But if I open a new window using javascript, then I can close this child window with javascript. I also need to close the parent window, please help me solve this issue. Below js code uses older version of chrome.

```
window.open('', '_self', ''); 
window.close();
```

And i'm not able to use any extension like 'close kiosk'. My company won't allow me to do such things.

Comment: I'm on Chrome 38 and when I run that code in the console the window closes. What exactly is the error that you are getting?

Comment: I didn't get any response yet

Answer (score 1):

You could try using:

```
self.close();
```

It works in Chrome, Safari, IE but not sure about Firefox.

Also, there's a new way to close windows using the new method window.close() in the dev version of Chrome: [see here](https://developer.chrome.com/dev/apps/app.window.html#type-AppWindow).
But I recommend using the first method as it currently works.

Comment: I just tried "window.open('', '_self', '');self.close();" but no use

Comment: If it's for your own use you can try to open up about:config and set
allow_scripts_to_close_windows to true. Otherwise, you can just try to ues open(location, '_self').close(); --- It's not recommended but it should work.

Comment: about:config is only available in firefox. Correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Yes, you're correct, i don't have a Chrome at work. Have you tried open(location, '_self').close() ?

Comment: yup, its just works only the older version of the chrome(ver 28)

Comment: Just installed and tested. Apparently I haven't been able to find a workaround...all methods generate "Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it." :(